# How to initialize a PDO connection inside a class so that other methods within that class can access that connection

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to use a PDO connection in a class, but I can't seem to get it right.

```
class core{

    public $dbh;

    public function __construct(){
       try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sales;charset=utf8', 'root', '0150000048785', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::  ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Another method within class "core";

```
public function varify_pwd(){

                    $varify = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = ?");
                    self::bindParams($varify, array($_SESSION['uid']), $dbh);
                    $row = $varify->fetch();                    

                    if (password_verify($pwd, $row['pwd'])){ 
                        return true;
                        exit;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                        exit;   
                    }
    }
}
```

How do I make the variable $dbh to be available to other methods?

Comment: Check [$this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class core{

public $dbh;

public function __construct(){
   try {
    //see here:
    $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sales;charset=utf8', 'root', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::  ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: "dbh" is undefined in varify_pwd();

Comment: you need to use $this->dbh everywhere.

Comment: Ok did that and its ok now.